# PHP mysql_query data size limit?

Tags: php, mysql, size, limit

I am trying to `UPDATE` a mysql `TEXT data-type column` with a string contains near 6,000 characters inside (6 kb data-size). Then the column is not updated with that data.

Then when i test this column by updating with test data around 100 characters, it works.

So, is there any limit on mysql query processing?

If so, how can i adjust it?

I'm using XAMPP on MacOSX.

Comment: AFAIK, If the limit was reached your data would be truncated - not ignored completely. Take PHP out of the equation and copy/paste the rendered query into mysql.

Comment: Have you ensured there are no special characters breaking your query?

Comment: `text` data type can have up to 65,535 characters. There is probably another problem with your data. Any special characters you are inserting?

Comment: Are you doing any error checking after your query? Can you show your code?

Comment: Oh, @Josh and other guys, thankssss about reminding special character. I was not checked it and now its ok by using `mysql_escape_string`. Thanks again :)

Comment: Query may also be timing out... also check MySQL error/slow query log...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try escaping your data properly. Your data would be truncated rather than denied (by default) by MySQL if it wouldn't fit. The max size for TEXT field is 64kb.

If your data contains characters like ' and " your query could fail. Add proper error handling to determine where and why things go wrong and escape your data accordingly.

Comment: Oh yes it is escaping problem. Now its ok with `mysql_escape_string` .. thanks :)

Comment: In that case, mark this question answered please.

Also, mysql_* is getting deprecated: http://cz.php.net/mysql_connect

Comment: Yes, MySQLI and PDO are replacing mysql_*. The deprecation process has begun, but it's not yet deprecated.

Comment: Actually, as of PHP 4.3.0, mysql_real_escape_string() should be used with MySQL extension instead of mysql_escape_string()